# RoR error - Mysql2::Error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I have one ruby on rails site running and working. I have created a new project and pointed the subdomain to it. That all worked.
I changed the database.yml to a new user I created in my database and I run `rake db:create` without any issues and the databases are created, but when I go to my subdomain in my browser I get the following error:

> Mysql2::Error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

Why is this?

Comment: Did your start your server with root level ?

Comment: I am using passenger and apache, I've set it up the exact same way as the other project.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by creating a restart.txt in the tmp directory of my project.
http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_redeploying_restarting_the_ruby_on_rails_application